# A polynomial has only real roots and all coefficients $\pm 1$. Prove the degree $<4$.

Tags: inequality, polynomials, roots

Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial with only real roots and all coefficients equal to $\pm 1$. Prove that the degree of the polynomial is less than 4.

This is practice for Putnam, but I am not certain where to begin. I know I need to use inequalities. Could this be a roots of unity problem?

Comment: Well $x^4+1$ has no real roots, so there's a start.

Comment: I think it's supposed to say "A polynomial has ONLY real roots".

Comment: Yes allow me to correct that. The source for the problem also made that mistake.

Comment: There's also the fact that primitive $n$th roots of unity are not real after $n=2$ and they are roots of cyclotomic polynomials, which *tend* to have only coefficients $\pm1$.

Comment: Just to state the obvious, all coefficients are supposed to be in $\{-1,0,1\}$.

Comment: The last time I checked, all roots of $X^{2013}$ were real...

Comment: Or maybe that was not so obvious. All coeffcients _up to the degree of the polynomial_ are supposed to be in ${-1,+1}$?

Comment: yes, otherwise $x^4-x^2$ would be an obvious counterexample.

Comment: Actually, we can weaken the assumption to all $|a_k| \le 1$ and the constant term $a_n = \pm 1$. A minor modification of leshik's answer will continue to work and force $n \le 3$.

Comment: @achillehui: and  $a_{n-1}=-1.$

Answer (score 10):

Let $P(x)=x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+...+a_n$ where all $a_i'$ s are $1$ or $-1$ and $x_1,x_2...x_n$ are all real roots of $P.$ By Viete's formulas $|x_1+x_2+...+x_n|=1$ and $x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_n^2=(x_1+x_2+...x_n)^2-2\sum_{i<j}x_ix_j=1-2a_{2}=3.$ Now we can estimate $3=x_1^2+x_2^2+...x_n^2\ge n\sqrt[n]{x_1^2x_2^2...x_n^2}=n$ so, $n\le 3$ and the result follows.