# About the degree of a polynomial that has only real roots and all coefficients are 1 except one

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, roots

I have a polynomial P with real coefficients of degree n, where all coefficients are equal to 1 except one. I need to prove that if the roots of P are all real, then necessarily n < 5. I just want to get an idea to approach this problem. I tried Descartes without success as mentioned in the [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4808110/about-real-roots-of-a-polynomial-with-real-coefficients-that-has-three-consecuti).

Comment: This is a variation of [this Putnam question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497159/a-polynomial-has-only-real-roots-and-all-coefficients-pm-1-prove-the-degree). It works similarly.

Comment: But the coefficient different from 1 can be zero, which poses a problem with the linking method

Comment: Hi :) Let $P(x) =\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k$. If $2\mid n$ and $a_n=a_{n-1}=a_{n-2}=1$, then $\sum_{k=0}^n\xi_k^2=-1$ where $\xi_k$ are the roots of $P$. Hence, one of $a_n, a_{n-1}, a_{n-2}$ needs to be different from 1. The idea is taken from @DietrichBurde 's link.

Comment: Didn't you show that if three consecutive coefficients are equal,the polynomial cannot have all real coefficients; but here you cannot have more than $5$ coefficients and not satisfy that (three consecutive coefficients one) so degree is at most $4$

Comment: Thank you, Conrad. You are right; if the degree of P is greater than or equal to 5, then necessarily, 3 consecutive terms are equal to 1.